# strange behavior overridden method. I have ann error

Tags: java, maven, interface, osgi, apache-karaf

I have some module in OSGi project.

```
payment
  - payment-api
  - payment-impl
```

in `payment-api` I have interface `UserService`

```
public interface UserService{
    String method1(String p1, int p2);
    String method2(String p1);
}
```

And implementation

```
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService{

@Override
public String method1(String p1, int p2){
   //code
   returnt result;
  }

@Override
public String method2(String p1){
   //code
   returnt result;
  }
}
```

And my module `payment-impl` has dependency

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>mydomain</groupId>
        <artifactId>payment-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

It work fine. But now, if i tried add new mrthod to `UserService` and after override this method in `UserServiceImpl` I have error:

```
public interface UserService{
        String method1(String p1, int p2);
        String method2(String p1);
        String test(int a);
    }
```

and

```
@Override
    public String test(int a) {
        return "sdfsdff";
    }

java:[94,9] method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
```

But if I delete `@Override` annotation all work fine. I cn not understand why?  how can this be?

```
 interface Y{
    String method();
    }

public class X implemets Y{
  @Override
  String method(){
  return "some string";
   }//is error

//------


String method(){
  return "some string";
   }//is fine

}
```

And if I not  implements this method compiler swears. And by default IDE override methosd with annotation. And another methods which have already been implemented work fine without annotations

Comment: This is pseudo-code and while thats fine for SO, please make sure that the example works in terms of recreating your code. The error code is *very specific* - have you tried to alter your pattern to respond to the error?

Comment: Just taking a guess here, the impl module might still be referencing a stale version of the api module. If that <dependency> node indicates Maven, you might want to rename your version 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT, clear your .m2 cache, and then clean and rebuild the product.

Comment: yes I tried. pseudocode end question. the first code of a real project, only method names changed.

Comment: @ Roman Thanks! It work

Comment: @user5620472 Great! I've worded it into an answer, if you are inclined to mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

The `impl` module might be referencing a stale version of the `api` module. You might want to rename your version `1.0.0-SNAPSHOT`, clear your local maven repository (typically found in `~/.m2/repository`), and then clean and rebuild the product.

I am uncertain whether suffixing the version with `SNAPSHOT` is important here, but it is not a bad practice to do so while the product is in development.

I am also uncertain exactly why you might have hit a stale version of the module. To really dig deep into the problem I would recommend:

1. Inspect the classpath that you use for running the application to determine/confirm the location where the api jar is being used from.
2. Understand what sequence of events ensures that that jar gets refreshed with your latest built code. Perhaps you always need to invoke `mvn install` and cannot just rely on the IDE compilation process, that I'm not sure.